# Plural or singular noun in this case?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

"The line graph illustrates the **amount** of goods which was delivered by road, water, rail and pipeline in the UK from 2000 to 2005".

Should I use **"amount"** or **"amounts"** in this case? (I am writing a report of a line graph with 4 lines, each of which depicts the amount of cargo transported by a particular mode of transport shown above)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With 4 lines, you need "which were" instead of "which was", but I'm not sure you can't still use 'amount'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Amount** would be preferred because the following word (goods) ends with **s** .

***More Mistakes***

As it is plural it will be **which were** and not **which was**.

Comment: my bad @JasonBassford (edited it)